# Trimming input using regex expression

Tags: java, regex, javafx

I have an input field where user input values. The values can have the following criteria:
1)integers(Further converted to double)
2)doubles
3)Can have either a plus or minus sign before them

This is the regex I created so far `^[-+]?\d{0,9}[.]?\d{0,9}\s{1}`

It catches a single double value with the space at the end, but fails to catch multiple(e.g. with "2.34, 45, 69" it will only recognize 2.34)

Also is there a way from preventing from pasting regex strings in input?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the comma.  Otherwise just need to wrap it in parenthesis and tack an asterisk on the end to let it know the pattern could repeat. Something like:

```
^([-+]?\d{0,9}[.]?\d{0,9}[,]?\s{1})*
```

Tested working at regex101

edit: to stop people from entering regex into the field, maybe something like:

```
[^[]\(\)[a-zA-z]\\\/\?\^]
```

This will tell it not to allow any of those characters, which are commonly used in regex.